# Interpretation of pc_status bit location from Xilinx AXI Protocol Checker IP

Tags: fpga, verilog, axi4

In the [pc_status error bit location](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/axi_protocol_checker/v2_0/pg101-axi-protocol-checker.pdf#page=17) , is it bit #32 because in the following simulation waveform, BVALID is never asserted high during the time when pc_status error bit #32 is asserted ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's reporting the error a few cycles later. But that is the problem--at the point BVALID is asserted, AWREADY is still 0 so the write handshake isn't complete.

Comment: A slave must not take BVALID HIGH until after the write address handshake is complete.Or A slave must not take BVALID HIGH until after the last write data handshake is complete.   <-- this explanation of pc_status[32] does not involve AWREADY !!!!!!

Besides, I am using AXI slave IP from Xilinx, so it is Xilinx code that triggers bith BVALID and AWREADY

Comment: @kevin AWREADY is part of the write address handshake.

Comment: but like I just said,  it is Xilinx AXI Slave IP that triggers both BVALID and AWREADY , not my AXI master code

Comment: and there should not be any X unknown state within pc_status vector, this is something very strange

Comment: You've got some X's at the beginning of your trace. Maybe you need to reset or something.

Comment: I extended reset for 1 more clock cycle, the X unknown states are gone now for pc_status

Comment: now I have [an entirely different pc_status issue](https://i.imgur.com/BUYqC5z.png)

Comment: You probably can't assert all of the WSTRB bits when writing to an address in the middle of the data word. Maybe the address should be incrementing by more than 1.

Comment: can't assert all of the WSTRB bits when writing to an address in the middle of the data word.  <-- is this requirement stated somewhere in the [AXI Protocol spec](https://static.docs.arm.com/ihi0022/g/IHI0022G_amba_axi_protocol_spec.pdf#page=54) ?

Comment: Yes: "The information on the low-order address lines must be consistent with the information on the byte lane strobes."

Comment: Why **the address should be incrementing by more than 1** ?

Comment: You're writing more than one byte, so if you don't want the writes overlapping then it should increment by more than one.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by **writes overlapping** ?

Comment: I do not see any **overlapping write** in this [simulation waveform](https://i.imgur.com/PoPzPfu.png) which has pc_status[22] bit [AXI_ERRM_WSTRB](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/axi_protocol_checker/v2_0/pg101-axi-protocol-checker.pdf#page=16) being asserted.

Comment: I'm getting messages about avoiding extended discussions here in comments. Maybe you should create a new question about the WSTRB error and/or the overlap.

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/486660/axi-wstrb-and-awaddr-issue-with-overlapping-writes